# How to related/associate to Mongo Collections in Meteor without using simple schema

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I am working on a meteor project.

Step 1

I've added the accounts-password and the accounts-ui packages so in order to have a users collection and an authenticating system.

Step 2

I've created a Mongo collection 'Posts' of documents with the following fields: _id, title, description and createdOn(date).

Step 3

I've created another Mongo collection 'Comments' of documents with the following fields: _id, comment ,postedOn('date') and createdBy(Meteor.user()._id)

Step 4

I've added the iron router package and set some routing. You can view a blog list and go to single post detail page.
I want to give the possibility to the users who are logged in to post comments
on a single comment without using the aldeed simple-schema package.

Find below some snippets from my project:

```
 Template.posts_list.helpers({
    posts:function(){
        return Posts.find({}, {sort: {createdOn: -1} });
    }
})
 Template.comments.helpers({
    comments:function(){
        return Comments.find({ ?????  Ho can I associate comments to a single post? });

    }
})
```

I am wondering how can I make the proper association between the 2 collections. I would like to show only those comments associated to the related post. As of now all the comments appear to every post without distinction. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a postId to your comments schema. Then, whenever you're submitting a comment, get the _id of the post in question and send it to your meteor method where you're inserting the comment.  Something like this:

```
// In your template events:
'submitCommentForm': function( event, template ) {
    var postId = this._id; // Make sure your post data context of this form is set in a #each or #with.
    Meteor.call('addComment', event.target.comment, postId, ...) // Assuming your comment is in some sort of named input with comment as the name.
}
```